# Reason for different behaviour in local and remote instances of Glassfish 4.0

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, glassfish

I have a Java EE 7 project which I have been able to successfully deploy to the embedded Glassfish 4 instance on my desktop. However, when I deploy the same project to a remote Glassfish 4 instance, the app does not behave properly.

The problem seems to be related to the scope of the two main bean instances in the app, both of which are declared as follows:

```
@Named   
@ViewScoped  
public class OfferListBean
```

..and

```
@Named  
@ViewScoped  
public class EditBean
```

When I deploy to the remote server, it throws the following exception:

```
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-000072 Bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable. Bean: Managed Bean [class beans.EditBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named] org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000072 Bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable. Bean: Managed Bean [class beans.EditBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named] at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkType(ManagedBean.java:210)
```

I discovered by looking on the net that this means that the bean needs to implement Serializable, so I implemented serializable, and the app deploys without exception. However, when the JSF pages try to access either of the beans, the following exception is thrown:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /offerreport/offerlist.xhtml @21,38 value="#{offerListBean.selectedManufacturer}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'offerListBean' resolved to null
```

The OS on my desktop is Windows 7, the server is Windows 2003. The local JDK is 1.8 the server is running on 1.7 (I compiled the app to 1.7 in Netbeans).

Any thoughts would be very greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason they are both Named and ManagedBean? I thought one was to choose 1 type of beans - JSF (ManagedBean) or CDI (Named). If this is on purpose don't you need both the 2 different ViewScopes also then?

Comment: To be honest I'm really new to JSF and so I'm not sure. My understanding was that it is necessary to use the @Named annotation in order to be able to refer to the bean from the JSF page, and indeed the app stopped working in the local environment when I removed '@Named'. However I just went and looked this up and you're right the '@Named' is redundant. I'll try and see if I can make it work without the '@Named'.

Comment: Yes use either named + inject or managedbean + managedproperty. But the first pair (CDI beans) are apparently "winning", and since you are using glassfish which has CDI installed it could be preferred. But as long as you choose one pair consistently. Also note there are two different ViewScoped-annotations (in different packages) for the two different types of beans.

Comment: Heres a kind of overview; JSF left, CDI right: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/mriem/archive/2013/10/30/jsf-tip-30-migrate-your-managedbean-named-annotations. When injecting in other beans JSF uses ManagedProperty, CDI uses Inject

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, that sounds really interesting - just so I know, what is the difference between the two packages (or better yet, which package should I choose)?

Comment: Packages in link. Hope all makes sense :-) CDI is preferred for future compatibility

Comment: I made those changes, as suggested, and it was absolutely the right thing to do. However, it still hasn't changed the behaviour on the remote server. The server still wants me to serialise the beans and it still doesn't instantiate the beans.

Comment: They should always implement Serializable, but even with this, it shows exact same error? (javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException...)

Comment: It does, and I have to wonder why no error was thrown on the local instance. But I fixed it, there was another bean that also needed to be serialized. Thanks for your help, I really do appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! The solution was that there was another, stateless, bean that was injected into both EditBean and OfferListBean and it needed to be serialized as well.

As for the reasons why there is a difference between the requirements for the local server and the remote, I suspect the problem is rooted in the two environments being different. The server is an old server running Windows Server 2003 which the company has let me experiment with. It can only run Java 7. My desktop runs Java 8.